# Flush single app django 1.9

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

My django project has multiple apps. I am trying to find a way to flush all the data from DB for a single django app. I found some ways to do in earlier versions of django but couldn't find something that could be used for version 1.9 .

Is there a way to do this or do I need to manually delete data from DB/create custom command for my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *migrate* command:

```
./manage.py migrate app_name zero
```

I used it in django-1.8. I am not sure about django-1.9 but it should work.

Comment: I changed some foreign keys to default to null so doing the above causes integrity issues.